# How to use only a part a tuple from return

Tags: python

This question maybe is a little awkward but i don't wanna unused variables. for example:

```
height, width = my_function()
```

i wanna use only the width value, there is a way to assign only the `width` value, example:

```
, width = my_function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to assign `width`, you can simply do `width = my_function()[1]`

Comment: Alternatively it's fairly common to see `_,width = my_function()` in Python code where `_` is a throwaway variable.

Comment: @Mike: I was just about to edit that in. I'd personally still assign both `height` and `width` for completeness, though.